# How do I remove an object from an array with a matching property?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following data:

```
food = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pizza',
  price: 16
};

orders = [
  { food_id: 2, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 2, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 1, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 3, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 1, table_id: 5 }
];
```

I want to remove a single item from the **orders** array matching `food_id`. Here's what I tried:

```
removeFoodOrder(food: Food): void {
  for (let order of this.orders) {
    let match = this.orders.filter((order) => order.food_id == food.id);
    match ? this.orders.splice(this.orders.indexOf(order), 1) : null;
    break;
  }
  console.log(this.orders);
}
```

If I call `removeFoodOrder(food)`, it removes the first element from the array no matter what food item I pass in the params.

```
removeFoodOrder(food) 
// removes {food_id: 2, table_id: 5} (the first element)
// I want to remove {food_id: 1, table_id: 5},
```

I want to target the matching element from the array and remove a **single** instance of it. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's removing the first element of the array because you've already removed the item with filter (I'm saying this without actually testing your code but I'm pretty sure that's what it is)

Comment: You have an unconditional break inside of your loop and you're using the ternary operator in an extremely suspicious way

Comment: @AluanHaddad I totally agree. That's just adding confusion

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
food = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pizza',
  price: 16
};

orders = [
  { food_id: 2, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 2, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 1, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 3, table_id: 5 },
  { food_id: 1, table_id: 5 }
];

removeFoodOrder(food: Food): void {
  this.orders = this.orders.filter(({ food_id }) => food_id !== food.id);        
}
```

**Edit:**

Since your array allows duplicate elements and you want to remove only the first match, you could use the [**`Array#findIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) + [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods:

```
const foundIndex = this.orders.findIndex(({ food_id }) => food_id === food.id);
this.orders = this.orders.filter((_, index) => index !== foundIndex);
```

Comment: Filter weeds out all matching elements. I only wish to remove one matching element.

Comment: Well, since the `food_id` isn't `unique`, how will you decide which element should be removed? The first.. the second.. the third? Think about it.

Comment: The first, of course. There can be many `{food_id: 2, table_id: 5}` duplicates in the orders array and I want to remove only one. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, `filter` method removes all elements that matches with a specific condition. Since your `array` allows duplicates, check the edit version with an alternative to tradittional `for loop`.

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)

Comment: you have to return the result other wise you will not get any result 

removeFoodOrder = (food: Food): void => {
return  this.orders = this.orders.filter(order => order.food_id !== food.id);        
}

Comment: @SreehariBallampalli huh? I'm mutating the `orders` array already in a VOID method. For what reason should I return anything?

Answer (score 3):

The first step for me is always to remove anything confusing like that ternary operator and your break stmt.
Here's how I did it

```
let food = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pizza',
  price: 16
}

let orders = [
    {food_id: 2, table_id: 5},
    {food_id: 2, table_id: 5},
    {food_id: 1, table_id: 5},
    {food_id: 3, table_id: 5},
    {food_id: 1, table_id: 5}
]

for (let order of this.orders) {
    if (food.id === order.food_id) {
        this.orders.splice(this.orders.indexOf(order), 1);
        break;
    }
}
console.log(this.orders);
```

I would recommend against using Array#filter if you don't know 100% how to use it.

**UPDATE** I am not saying don't use the Array#filter method. I'm just saying that if your code isn't working, you should try to remove anything that could be causing your issue and try to go about it step by step using simple constructs (like a for loop and if stmt).

Comment: It's not a question of whether you should use filter or not is a question of what you're trying to do. If you want to create new array without the item in it filter is the right choice

Comment: @AluanHaddad You're absolutely right. I guess what I meant to say was the fastest way to solve a problem like this is to eliminate anything that one doesn't understand completely and try to fix it using basic constructs.

Comment: This answer is correct and works and is much better than the other answer but I don't think you should steer people away from filter because it's an extremely elegant and useful function. It may not be the right choice here though. Just remarking.

Comment: Good explanation. This is the right solution because using filter would create a new array weeding out the matching elements. Is there a way to use filter to create a new array weeding out only one matching element?

Comment: It depends if the element is unique or not. If it's not, then no (unless you do unholy things to it). If it is, then you would just use filter as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to remove one instance from an orders array with multiple instances of {food_id: 2, table_id: 5} using Filter? I don't understand the need for it to be unique.

Comment: the filter function will remove everything that matches the description you provide. If you have more than 1 item that has the same id in the data structure, then it will remove every item with that id

Comment: I just noticed a big issue with this answer and suggested an edit. This answer is less well typed than the original problem. Get rid of the anys

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeFoodOrder(food: Food): void
{
    for (let order of this.orders) {
        if (order.food_id == food.id) {
            this.orders.splice(this.orders.indexOf(order), 1);
            break;
        }      
    }
    console.log(this.orders);
};
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you please elaborate on poor style?

Comment: The use of `==` as well as the addition of irrelevant abstractions and unnecessary type annotations.